# arcGIS javascript no lat long after doing Feature Layer query

Tags: esri, arcgis-js-api, esri-maps

I have done a query on my feature layer and got a result. the only problem is that the resulting object doesn't contain a LAT and LNG attribute. Here is the problem:

```
centerAndZoomOnAsset(assetId: string) {
let query = this.pipeFL.createQuery();
query.where = `AssetId = '${assetId}'`;
query.outFields = ['*'];
this.pipeFL.queryFeatures(query).then((result: esri.FeatureSet) => {
  debugger;
  const foundFeatureGraphic: esri.Graphic = result.features[0];
  if (foundFeatureGraphic) {
    const center = foundFeatureGraphic.geometry.extent.center.clone();
```

At this point I have a value for center, and it has it's x,y coords, however, I do not have: center.latitude or center.longitude...
I don't see why it will not have it. When I do a hit test on a click, it contains both lat and lng, but when i query from outside of the hit test, it doesn't contain my lat and lng.
Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: center.x is center.longitude

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `returnGeometry` parameter to true in order to get spatial data from the query. [See the API here](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/query-feature-service-.htm)

Try using this:

```js
centerAndZoomOnAsset(assetId: string) {
let query = this.pipeFL.createQuery();
query.where = `AssetId = '${assetId}'`;
query.returnGeometry = true;
query.outFields = ['*'];
this.pipeFL.queryFeatures(query).then((result: esri.FeatureSet) => {
  debugger;
  const foundFeatureGraphic: esri.Graphic = result.features[0];
  if (foundFeatureGraphic) {
    const center = foundFeatureGraphic.geometry.extent.center.clone();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try defining `outSpatialReference` property in your query for the queryFeature call

```
query.outSpatialReference = mapView.spatialReference;
```